# Python function parameter ([x[,y[,z]]]) meaning

Tags: python, parameters

I have come across this kind of method signature in python docs. What does it mean? eg.

```
smtplib.SMTP([host[, port[, local_hostname[, timeout]]]]
```

In general syntax such as `function([x[,y[,z]]])`?

Comment: It simply means that those parameters are optional.

Comment: And it's not Python specific.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This refers to optional parameters, with each bracket denoting another level of specificity in terms of the function call (in this case, the function is actually a constructor for an SMTP instance). So you can call...

```
smtplib.SMTP(host)
```

or

```
smtplib.SMTP(host, port)
```

or

```
smtplib.SMTP(host, port, local_hostname)
```

or

```
smtplib.SMTP(host, port, local_hostname, timeout)
```

If you look in [the example](https://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html#smtp-example) for this module, they call

`server = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')`

which would be the first version of the constructor above

EDIT: As was correctly pointed out by [arshajii](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1357341/arshajii), this is not a syntax, but merely a documentation style

Answer (score 5):

Parameters enclosed in brackets are optional. For example,

```
foo(x[, y])
```

would mean that `x` is required but `y` is optional. In your case, all of the parameters are marked as optional.

Note that this is *not* the syntax of the Python language, but rather a documentation convention.